# C++ Win32 IStream to string problems

Tags: c++, winapi, stream

NOTE: I have googled, searched and tried out every single thing I found.

The real issue is that I am trying to use `IStream` with things like `get, getline, read, put`

The error, `IStream has no member named 'read'`

The code:

```
// For version info and etc
HRSRC srcTest =   FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(2), RT_VERSION);
HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, srcTest);

// Gets the size of the resource, and locks it to get a pointer
int size = SizeofResource(NULL, srcTest); 
LPVOID resPtr = LockResource(hGlobal); 

hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, size); 

// Copies the raw data into allocated space
 memcpy(hGlobal, resPtr, size);

// Cleans
FreeResource(hGlobal);

// Creates a stream 
IStream* in = NULL;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, true, &in);


// One example test
std::string ret;
char buffer[4096];

while (in->read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))

ret.append(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
ret.append(buffer, in.gcount());
```

The resource is coming directly from `VERSION_INFO` in the resource file. I have tested and that is absolutely not the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using the same `hGlobal` variable for both `LoadResource()` and `GlobalAlloc()`. You are calling `FreeResource()` on the `HGLOBAL` returned by `GlobalAlloc()`, not the one returned by `LoadResource()`.  Consider using `SHCreateMemStream()` instead of `GlobalAlloc()` and `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`.

Comment: Don't add a new question to an existing one, ask a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive; the method is named [`Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380011(v=vs.85).aspx) (it's actually defined in `ISequentialStream` which `IStream` inherits from).

Note that it takes three parameters, not the two you are trying to pass it.

> HRESULT Read(   [out] void  *pv,
>                   [in]  ULONG cb,   [out] ULONG
>   *pcbRead );
>
> Parameters
>
> pv [out] A pointer to the buffer which the stream data is read into.
>
> cb [in] The number of bytes of data to read from the stream object.
>
> pcbRead [out] A pointer to a ULONG variable that receives the actual
>   number of bytes read from the stream object.